# How to mock fake url with axios for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, axios

**Context**

The URL in this app is only accessible in production and it is not able to access via local. When doing unit tests, I need to mock the response of that url.

**What I got**

Follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@lucaspenzeymoog/mocking-api-requests-with-jest-452ca2a8c7d7)

**Code I have**

saga.js

```
import {all, call, put, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';

async function myfetch(endpoint) {
  const out = await axios.get(endpoint);
  return out.data;
}

function* getItems() {
  //const endpoint = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  const endpoint = 'http://sdfds';
  const response = yield call(myfetch, endpoint);
  const items = response;

  //test
  console.log('items', items);

  yield put({type: 'ITEMS_GET_SUCCESS', items: items});
}

export function* getItemsSaga() {
  yield takeEvery('ITEMS_GET', getItems);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([getItemsSaga()]);
}
```

You can see that I made endpoint as const `endpoint = 'http://sdfds';`, which is not accessible.

saga.test.js

```
// Follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@lucaspenzeymoog/mocking-api-requests-with-jest-452ca2a8c7d7
import SagaTester from 'redux-saga-tester';
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import reducer from '../reducer';
import {getItemsSaga} from '../saga';

const initialState = {
  reducer: {
    loading: true,
    items: []
  }
};

const options = {onError: console.error.bind(console)};

describe('Saga', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({key: 'val'}));
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('Showcases the tester API', async () => {
    const sagaTester = new SagaTester({
      initialState,
      reducers: {reducer: reducer},
      middlewares: [],
      options
    });

    sagaTester.start(getItemsSaga);

    sagaTester.dispatch({type: 'ITEMS_GET'});

    await sagaTester.waitFor('ITEMS_GET_SUCCESS');

    expect(sagaTester.getState()).toEqual({key: 'val'});
  });
});
```

axios.js

```
const axios = {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({data: {}}))
};
export default axios;
```

I was hopping this will overwrite the default `axios`

[Full code here](https://github.com/kenpeter/test-saga)

**Summary**

Need to overwrite default axios' return response.

Comment: Did you try moxios? https://www.npmjs.com/package/moxios

Comment: @FarhadYasir, https://github.com/kenpeter/test-saga/blob/master-mock/src/saga.test.js, not working. Could you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace a module, you need to save your mock module in a specific folder structure: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules

So it seems that in your project - [https://github.com/kenpeter/test-saga/blob/master-fix/src/**tests**/saga.test.js](https://github.com/kenpeter/test-saga/blob/master-fix/src/__tests__/saga.test.js) - you need to move the `__mocks__` folder the root, where `package.json` is. Then import axios normally like `import mockAxios from 'axios'`, and jest should take care of replacing the module.